# How should one use a Tor or a proxy service on a virtual machine?

Tags: anonymity, virtual-machine

When I'm running a virtual machine, say VirtualBox, if I wanted to use a proxy or service like tor or a VPN, if I only use that on my guest machine, would that be enough? No proxy, service, VPN, nothing on the host machine.

For example, host machine running Win7 connecting directly to the internet.
Guest machine running WinVista and using tor to browse internet

Does not having anything on the host machine make a difference? I have noticed when using a VPN on a host machine to get a different IP, but nothing on the guest machine resulted in the guest machine also having the new IP, since I assume the internet is coming through from the host.

Comment: "would that be enough?" for what? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Be aware that your guest OS is *not* shielded from spyware on the host.

Comment: @Pielco11 Sorry, what I mean is would it be enough stay as anonymous as using a non-VM computer. By not having any proxy or VPN on my host computer would that be a flaw and display my real IP when I browse the internet on my guest machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of it depends on the network setting for your guest OS in VirtualBox.
In NAT mode, your guest sits *behind* your host. In bridged mode, your guest sits *next to* your host. (Network wise.) It sounds like you use NAT, so the guest connects through the host.

As long as the guest can see the internet, it can connect to a VPN server or to the Tor network. You don't need to run anything on the host for that. In your case, if you do have a VPN active on your host, the guest will connect *through* that VPN *to* its own VPN or to Tor.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jobiwan. So even if I use NAT and have my guest behind the host, and don't use any VPN or proxy on my host, my IP address won't be leaked when I browse the internet with my guest(using tor)?

Comment: Correct.  On the outside of your router, everything looks the same as if you ran Tor Browser on a *real* (not virtual) machine.